# IE11 Developer Tools Network Tab Request Details Multiple Start

Tags: javascript, http-post, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I ran into a strange behavior. So in IE11, monitoring the network traffic for my application using the F12 Dev Tools, looking at a specific POST request in Details mode, there are two "Start" timings.

This behavior only occurs in IE11, not in Chrome or Firefox.
It is reproducible every time and runs FAR slower than the same request on other browsers. Also I noted that when testing in Chrome and FF, the request completed in less than a second compared to the 20+ seconds in IE11.

Also, oddly though the request completes in less than a second in Chrome, if I back up a page and issue the request again it takes 7 seconds, if I repeat it grows slowly each time (7.15 s, 7.55 s, 8.15 s, etc).

Can anyone tell me why this would happen or have any insights?

Thanks

[Screenshot Double Start IE11 Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKTMX.jpg)

Comment: Could this be related to https in IE?

Comment: i have the same issue too. did you find any solution for this?